# Open emacs from terminal like vim?

Tags: emacs

When I use `vi file.txt` my terminal is replaced with a vim session.

I'm toying with emacs and when I use `emacs file.txt` a second window opens up with emacs.

Is there a way to use the behaviour of vim with emacs? Specifically I want to open emacs from terminal have it take over the screen, then when I quit be back in my previous terminal session.

Comment: [Asked in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746227/how-to-open-emacs-inside-bash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want `emacs -nw file.txt`

Comment: thanks do you know how I can select the menu items in the terminal mode?

Comment: ``M-` `` should run the menu.